# Is there any generalized symbol for an electrolytic or electroplating cell?

Tags: basic, symbol, standard, electrolysis

Is there any symbol for an electrolytic cell? An electroplating cell, for instance?

(There are commonly used symbol for electrochemical cell (battery symbol). But symbol for electrolytic cell not seen. Neither in electricals , nor in electronics )

**I've seen a symbol for a kind-of electrolytic cell**, the [Voltameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltameter), ( that was used for chemical arithmetic (stoichiometry) and charge-calculation.

[image: cell symbol with chemical labels: Cu, Ag, H2O]

But the use of this symbol is so-rare (I've seen this symbol only in a few school textbooks, and [this](http://www.uq.edu.au/_School_Science_Lessons/32.2.00.GIF) website containing the image below).

[image: symbol used in a website]

The bottom portion of the image from that website also contains the symbol, labeled as "voltameter".

The school textbooks also used this symbol in some small circuits also.

**But I did not find this symbol in standard-sources or encyclopedias, etc.**

So I want to know,

1. Could I use this symbol to indicate any-kind of electrolytic cell  (such as electroplating cells? ) or it is the symbol for only that measuring device?
2. If not, then, is there a more general symbol, applicable for any-kind of electrolytic cell?.
3. Is there any standard source where this symbol is described properly?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any standard symbol for such a non-standard component.

Comment: Electrochemical cell and electrolytic cell, are 2 very much fundamental component of  electrical science. Maybe the second-one is not so-much used or sold-readymade. but both are very basic component.

Comment: yes, but not components of a circuit, unless your electrolytic cell is used as a battery, or your electromechanical as some kind of motor/actuator/generator/electromagnet.

Comment: @ Markus Muller Didn't understood the sentence clearly.  I did Not told eletromechanical . I told electrochemical cell (Synonymous to battery cell, that converts chemical energy to electric energy), and electrolytic cell(that takes in electric energy, and perform electrolysis with it, ie perform some chemical work). And if i can use an electrolytic cell as a battery, it then will not be called electrolytic cell anymore. it then will became a Electrochemical cell.

Comment: sorry I misread electrochemical for electromechanical cell, a term that I've never heard. Sorry! So, still, an electrolytic cell is not a common element in a circuit. I think you don't see a common symbol because it's a very uncommon thing, no matter how elementary it is, as it has little practical usage as component of larger systems, aside from the battery.

Comment: @ Markus its ok. However, electrolysis is not rare in industrial (large or minute) electrical works. But much realistic diagrams are used than symbols. However i assume certainly there are some origin of this symbol. because, at least in some places i saw the symbol. maybe the symbol became obsolete because it is too-much theoretical in use.

Comment: For what it's worth, several of the symbols in your lower diagram (including the "voltameter") are rare or nonstandard.

Comment: once in an website, i have seen an almost same-symbol in a modern electronic circuit (a **capacitor-symbol in a circle**) in a circuit. I forgot whose symbol it was (not a neon lamp probably). The only difference is, the plates were much nearby. otherwise the 2 symbols were confusingly similar.

Comment: You are correct that kind of gadget (electrolytic cell) is very rare outside textbooks. And you have identified the most common symbols used in textbooks. Therefore, it would appear that you have answered you own question. This is very much like your other questions like "is there a symbol for insulation". You may have unrealistic expectations to find "standard symbols" for things where they don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a symbol for "Conductivity cell", in STD 315-1975.

[image]

I hope this help you.

Comment: You're a symbol-detective detective.

Comment: :-D Looking how to make the perfect schematic I discovered the standard for symbols and reference designations.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *single* generalized symbol, because the most well-known electrical symbols usually denote either basic components (transistors, electrolytic capacitors, etc.) or enclosed products (amplifiers, sources, outputs). Beyond the classics you see in circuit design programs, there is a wider class of sketch-like symbols that most will figure out, like the "winding on soft iron core", which could be included in diagrams, perhaps accompanied by "soft Fe".

The idea of an electrochemical cell is fundamental enough that the question is very reasonable. However, the fact the images you provided appear at the top of my image search results for *electroplating cell electrical symbol* suggests there is no firm shorthand for this. I would suggest the sort of diagram used for chemistry labs:

[image: http://www.smartlearner.mobi/science/VideoPastPapers/Redox/Redox.htm]

Replace "battery" with a DC cell symbol, drop the ammeter if unneeded, maybe add waves to the surface, and the concept will get across and take up no more space than the "electrical circuit" in the sample image.